# Keras OOM for data validation using GPU

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, out-of-memory, gpu

I'm trying to run a deep model using GPU and seems `Keras` is running the validation against the whole validation data set in one batch instead of validating in many batches and that's causing out of memory problem:

> ```
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM
> when allocating tensor with shape[160000,64,64,1] and type double on
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
> [Op:GatherV2]
> ```

I did not have this problem when I was running on CPU, it's just happening when I'm running on GPU, my fit code looks like this

```
history = model.fit(patches_imgs_train, patches_masks_train, batch_size=8,
                    epochs=10, shuffle=True, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)
```

When I delete the validation parameter from the `fit` method the code works, but I need the validation.

Comment: Keras runs the validation step in batches, so you would need to show that this is not happening, which versions of keras and tensorflow? is it tf.keras?

Comment: [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) is a good option as it iterates over data from *disk*. You can create a dataset object like this: `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((imgs_train, masks_path)) ` of course after doing necessary per-processing. Finally, you can simply pass the dataset object to your `model.fit()`.

Answer (score 2):

Since no one is answering this, I can offer you a workaround.  You can separate fit() and evaluate() and run the evaluation on CPU.

You'll have to split your data manually to provide the testx and testy to evaluate().

```
for i in range(10):
    with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
       model.fit(x, y, epochs=1)

    with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
        loss, acc = model.evaluate(testx, testy)
```

You'll need deal with the accuracy values if you wanted some early stop.

It isn't perfect but it'll allow you to run much larger networks without OOMs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Rah That's will be great if it could work, I was really thinking to do something close, but was not sure how, I was really hoping if I could apply the batch size on the validation set, but seems not working.
Anyway, will try your way and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

So I could consider what is happening as a bug in Keras implementation, looks like it's trying to load the whole data set to the memory for splitting it into validation and training sets and it's not related to batch size, after trying many ways to go around it I found the best way to approach it is splitting the data using sklearn train_test_split instead of splitting it down in the fitting method using validation_split param.

```
x_train, x_v, y_train, y_v = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.2,train_size =0.8)

history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,
              batch_size=16,
              epochs=5,
              shuffle=True,
              verbose=2,
              validation_data=(x_v, y_v))
```